# Change background color of console output in C and C++

Tags: c++, c

I change the background and text color in my console by using the "system" command.

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
system ("color 1a");
cout <<"Hello World";

cin.ignore();
return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to change color in only one line? C or C++ are fine.
Thanks.

Comment: There is certainly a better way than the system command, but it will be platform dependent and you didn't mention the platform you're using.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you are using Windows, as your `system()` function is executing `color` which is a console utility for Windows.

If you are going to write your program for Windows and you want to change color of text and/or background, use this:

```
   SetConsoleTextAttribute (GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), attr);
```

Where `attr` is a combination of values with `|` (bitwise OR operator), to choose whther you want to change foreground or background color. Changes apply with the next function that writes to the console (`printf()` for example).

Details about how to encode the `attr` argument, here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682088%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_win32_character_attributes

For example, this programs prints "Hello world" using yellow text (red+green+intensity) over blue background, in a computer with Windows 2000 or later:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
  SetConsoleTextAttribute (GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FOREGROUND_RED |
                                                            FOREGROUND_GREEN | 
                                                            FOREGROUND_INTENSITY | 
                                                            BACKGROUND_BLUE
                          );
  printf ("Hello world\n");
  return 0;
}
```

---

This other shows a color chart showing all combinations for foreground and background colors:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
  unsigned char b,f;

  for (b=0;b<16;b++)
  {
    for (f=0;f<16;f++)
    {
        SetConsoleTextAttribute (GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), b<<4 | f);
        printf ("%.2X", b<<4 | f);
    }
    printf ("\n");
  }
  SetConsoleTextAttribute (GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 0x07);
  printf ("\n");
  return 0;
}
```