# Cant escape an ascii character in c

Tags: c

Hey guys am a newbie in c programming actually..I have a char array and am trying to keep the elements in an order. I have done it scuccefully but when i print the elements of the array an extra character `ÿ` happens in my code.

My code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

char values[4] = "mmfa";
int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void  * b)
{
   return(*(char*)a - *(char*)b);
}

int main()
{
   int n;


   qsort(values, 5, sizeof(char), cmpfunc);
   printf("\nAfter sorting the list is: \n");

   for( n = 0 ; n < 5; n++ )
 {
    printf("%c ", values[n]);
 }

   return(0);
}
```

When i print this i get the result `ÿ a f m m`.I need to remove the `ÿ`..I have tried it by escaping the aray with `\` but it didnt worked out.So how would i able to remove the `ascii code` from the result.

Thanx for the help

Comment: don't sort 5 values if you have only 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char values[4] = "mmfa";
```

Strings are terminated with `\0` so chage your array size to `char values[5]` .

Note `index 5` is for `null character`.

### EDIT

```
     for( n = 0 ; n < 5; n++ )
   {
         printf("%c ", values[n]);
   }
```

In this loop `n` goes till `4` where as your array is till `3` .Remember array index starts with `0` .

Also while calling `qsort` parameters should be -

```
      qsort(values, 4, sizeof(char), cmpfunc);
                     ^because number of elements in array is 4 not 5 .
```

Comment: then i got a small box like infront of the program

Comment: i did this code still it gives me a small symbol like box infront of the program'

Comment: @babxpox  please show definition of function qsort.

Comment: @babxpox please see above and now your code give correct output.

Comment: but the small symbol is still there..:o

Comment: @babxpox  you changed array size to `5` and in `qsort` to `4` .Then I don't think you should get wrong output.

Comment: which compiler are you using /

Comment: @babxpox I am using gcc 4.8 version.

Comment: thanx it worked..i have a question ..i want the output of this program to a new window of different style ..when user click the .exe file of this program i want to have a different window opened for it and display the output ..will i have to use c sharp for this ?

Comment: @babxpox  Well actually when you will click `.exe` file of this program it open in a different window . And you can add background or text color accordingly by `c` only . But I don't get what you mean by style?

Comment: style means the background ans colour ..if you have good tutorials  for that can you give me a link to acheieve this task ?

Comment: @babxpox  This link is good for it -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20725769/change-background-color-of-console-output-in-c-and-c   Method here is better than system command .

Comment: @babxpox  Also you can use header graphics.h and its function -http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/graphics.h                 see `setbkcolor()` in it .

Comment: but when i open the exe file it opens and closes so fast

Comment: @babxpox Just add `getchar()` before `return`.

Comment: wow thanx ..finally one more question ..how can i add an input bar to accept the user input in c ??..is this provision available ?

Comment: @babxpox you can get help from here -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667194/input-bar-at-console-bottom-in-c

Comment: @babxpox  well leave it .Use this  -http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/160896-createwindow-input-box-timer-functioning-help/

Answer (score 0):

Declare the char array like this

```
char values[] = "mmfa";
```

and change the `qsort` call to

```
qsort(values, strlen(values), sizeof(char), cmpfunc);
```

**Output**

```
After sorting the list is: 
a f m m
```

See Demo http://ideone.com/v3r9ir.